# What are the indicators near players in nba2k11?

Tags: nba2k11

I've been playing NBA 2k11 in the Wii, and I've noticed several indicators appear near the players. So far, I've seen some that I can't understand their meaning:

- A number 3 (you can see it on Paul Pierce, from the Celtics)
- A strength bar
- Some other icons I can't even identify!

Is there any online guide I can check to learn this?

Comment: Not surprisingly, the [online manual](http://cdn.steampowered.com/Manuals/65950/NBA2K11_PC_onlinemanual_v1.pdf?t=1303515701) (through Steam, although it appears to be the 360 manual) says absolutely nothing about the other icons. It would be nice to round out the accepted answer with the others if it were possible to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 indicates that the player has a three point shot

The strength bar that i think you are refering to is the players turbo and his fatigue level

The other icons that you can't recognise may be due to the wii poor graphics capabilites and not the icons itself but i could be wrong (never played it on the wii only on PS3)

hope this helps.

Comment: there is also an icon that looks like wings, that is an indication that they are a good dunker/has a high vertical (I think)